# Can an electrostatic field itself be insulated, as opposed to creating resistance to a current?

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, charge

Is it possible to insulate an electrostatic field itself, as opposed to preventing electrons from moving by creating resistance?

Specifically, if we position an isolated charge on one side of a resistant barrier that the charge itself cannot penetrate, and we have an electrostatic field on the other side of the barrier, will the electrostatic field act on the charge?

Here is a crude diagram, where q is the charge:

q |:::::::| field

I believe an answer to this question will have two parts:

(1) Will the charge move towards the barrier and then stop, exerting a force on the barrier? Or will the charge simply be stationary because there is no field on the other side of the barrier?

The key distinction being that in one case, the barrier prevents the field itself from reaching the charge; in the other, the barrier simply prevents the electron from moving through it.

(2) Is there a type of barrier (i.e., a substance of some kind) that is thought to be capable of "blocking", or diminishing, the force of an electrostatic field itself, as opposed to creating resistance to charges?

Note I am not asking whether we can cancel out an electrostatic field with an opposing one, which would for all practical purposes work as an insulator. I am instead asking whether there is a substance that blocks the field itself, rather than cancelling it out. E.g., plastics are generally poor conductors of electricity, but would plastic also shield a free-standing charge from an electrostatic field? I think the answer is no, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: FWIW, an electric field can be [screened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric-field_screening) .

Comment: Thanks, but that seems like it uses charges to weaken an electric field. I.e., I have a bunch of charges that together weaken some external field. I'm asking whether there's a substance capable of preventing electrostatic interactions from taking place across a barrier, without "negating" the field. This would be tantamount to blocking the force-carriers of the electrostatic force.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the details of the barrier.

If the barrier is made by putting a grounded metal between the source of the field and the test charge, then the test charge will be still attracted to the barrier, due to electrostatic induction.

If the barrier is made of dielectric with fixed polarization that is just so so to shield the source of the electrostatic field, but is not itself easily polarizable by test charge, then the test charge will not be attracted towards the barrier much.

Comment: Thanks. In the latter case, is the dielectric barrier thought of as physically blocking the force carriers of the electrostatic field?

Comment: Electrostatic field has no "force carriers". It just pervades all space.

Comment: I see. Then is the dielectric barrier thought of as locally diminishing the strength of the electrostatic field?

In contrast, my understanding is that you cannot insulate a magnetic, or gravitational field. Are you saying that a dielectric can in fact insulate an electrostatic field, as opposed to creating resistance to a current?

Comment: I think this is actually a point of semantics. I'm asking whether the electrostatic FORCE has a carrier, and I believe the answer is generally thought to be yes. So to rephrase: does the dielectric block the carrier of the electrostatic force.

Answer (score 0):

There are two frameworks that describe electric magnetic and electromagnetic interactions.

The classical, which includes electrostatics and the definition of an [electric field](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefie.html) , which includes the concept of a "test charge" to be seen. There are no force carriers in this framework. In the quantum mechanical framework there exists the photon, which is a building block for light, i.e. electromagnetic radiation. The photon, mathematically only, in what is called a "[virtual" form](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) can describe the interaction of an electric field with a charged particle, *but it needs quantum mechanics to understand it.* The classical theory is sufficient to describe electrostatics etc, the quantum is needed only in particular cases, of which your example is not one.

To isolate an electric field one has to realize that field lines have to start and end up on charged matter.  Your q in the question has an electric field itself, and depending on the barrier it will generate an [image  of itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges) in a conducting metal barrier, so it will be attracted,but by its image charge, *not by the field behind the barrier* which will be  in a [faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) and cannot cross it.

Thus with a metal barrier the field  interacts with the metal surface but does not cross it, and the charge on the other side which has a field again does not cross it.

With different materials various levels of crossover will be seen.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not assuming the barrier is necessarily metal. I'm asking, as a general matter, is there a substance that is capable of stopping the electrostatic field itself from penetrating the substance, as opposed to preventing charges from penetrating the substance.

Comment: metal only is used in faraday cages , which is what you are really asking, isolation of an electric field. all other materials will be permeable

Comment: Right, so that would really be a case of cancelling out an electrostatic field. I.e., a Faraday cage doesn't really "block" an external field, it instead creates an opposing field, thereby creating a net field of zero inside the cage, right? What I'm asking is instead, is there a substance that actually blocks the force of an electrostatic field itself - i.e., blocks the force-carriers of the field.

Comment: The atoms on the metal surface of the farraday cage do that. You have to realize that test charges should exist to define an electric field .The field itself is not a force, a test charge is needed for a force to be manifested. Non metals are not as effective, depending on the material and thickness the field will get through, to be available for test charges outsid the barrier, and the field ouside will be built up by the fields of the atoms and molecules that are on the material. Metals block all this.

Comment: There are no force carriers of the field in classical electrodynamics. An even in quantum, the virtual photons are  just a mathematical trick.

Comment: OK so you're saying the electric force penetrates non-metals, but does not penetrate certain metals. Seems to me like that's because metals have their own electrostatic fields that cancel out the external fields right? If so, that's an answer to a different question.

Comment: look at the capacitor , two parallel plates , in my first link. that is what you will get with a field inside

Comment: Right, thanks. I see two fields that cancel each other out. My understanding is that there is generally assumed to be an actual force carrier of the electrostatic force. Is there a substance that can block this force carrier from penetrating it? This is a completely different question from whether we can cancel an external electrostatic field with another offsetting one.

Comment: There is no electric force per se. Only electric fields and charges will interact with the field and a force will manifest. The field itself is not a force. Trying to penetrate a barrier it ends up on the charges within the barrier, and depending on the atomic structure, there is reflection for metals and partial penetration of non metals.

Comment: Great, so is there a substance that can prevent an electrostatic interaction from occurring across a barrier made of that substance, with the reason being due to something other than an offsetting local field? Seems to me like the answer is no.

Comment: Once again, a metal surface will do it everytime.

Comment: Once again, that's because it generates an offsetting field. Is there a substance that does it for a different reason?

Comment: Not that I know of.